# Count elements in string

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

I have string:  `'001;002;005'`
I want count `;` in my string.

e.g.:

```
select count('001;002;005', expression)
```

returns 2

```
select count('001;002;005;006', expression)
```

returns 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
select length(regexp_replace('001;002;005', '[^;]', '', 'g'));

 length 
--------
      2
(1 row)
```

The expression `[^;]` means *any character other than semicolon*.

Comment: Thank you. helpful.

Answer (score 4):

```
select length(<your string>) - length(translate(<your string>, ';', ''));
```

Comment: @xQbert And most efficient on my tests :o) (with regexp ~ 3000ms, arrays ~ 500ms, mine ~ 300ms, tests on `random()::text` with `0` as separator)